# How can I install 'ServerAgent' on the Application server to monitor its performance using Jmeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-plugins

**I am using 'jp@gc - PerfMon Metrics Collector' Lister for this and as you know it requires 'ServerAgent' running on the connecting server.**

Step by step instruction would be very helpful.

***And also, if anyone knows of any better alternatives to monitor the servers using jmeter then please share with me, it would be a great help.***

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the below Steps:

1. Download ServerAgent2.2.1.zip file(URL: http://jmeter-plugins.org/downloads/all/)
2. Unzip and Paste the folder in the  Machine where Server is hosted.
3. Run startAgent.sh(Linux) and startAgent.bat(Windows) in the Server Machine.
4. Get the Server IP and add the same in the Jmeter Properties File.
           `remote_hosts=`
5. Add the (Perfmon metrics collector)Listener in the Test Plan.
6. Host/IP: Add the Server Host/IP
7. Port: By default 4444
8. Metrics to be collected: What metric you want to collect.

Comment: i tried upto point 4 for many times but couldn't get the option of perfmon matrics collector in listeners' list